# Как с помощью медиазапроса поменять значение js

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью медиазапроса поменять значение этой строки? slidesPerView: 1,

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {  
      slidesPerView: 1,
      direction: getDirection(),
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      on: {
        resize: function () {
          swiper.changeDirection(getDirection());
        },
      },
    });

    function getDirection() {
      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      var direction = window.innerWidth <= 760 ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal';

      return direction;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте breakpoints. Подробнее тут: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints

Пример:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Default parameters
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!